# Ice namespace error

Tags: authentication, namespaces, docker, ibm-cloud, ice

I'm trying to login to stage1 Bluemix (for IBMers) using command:

```
ice --verbose login --user username --psswd password  --registry 'registry-ice.bluemix_staging_server'
```

Once invoked I'm prompted:

```
 Namespace(api_key=None, api_url=None, cf=False, cloud=False, host=None, local=False, org=None, psswd='password', reg_host='registry-ice.bluemix_staging_server', skip_docker=False, space=None, subparser_name='login', user='username', verbose=True)
    Executing: cf login -u username -p password -a https://api.bluemix_staging_server
    API endpoint: https://api.bluemix_staging_server
    Authenticating...
    OK

Targeted org 'user org'

Select a space (or press enter to skip):
1. dev
2. docker
```

Once I choose `dev` or `docker`  I get following error:

```
 ------------------------
*Error response from daemon: Login: You must set a namespace before you login to the registry.  See 'ice help namespace' (Code: 404; Headers: map[Server:[nginx] Date:[Tue, 10 Nov 2015 10:54:06 GMT] Content-Type:[text/plain] Content-Length:[84] Connection:[keep-alive]])
docker is not available on your system or is not properly configured
Could not authenticate with cloud registry at registry-ice.bluemix_staging_server
You can still use IBM Containers but will not be able to run local docker containers, push, or pull images*
 ------------------------
```

I've defined a space named 'docker' using console before logging.

Any idea what I'm missing here?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the namespace before doing the login (namespace is your area within the Images Registry). It is done just once.

Check the docs here: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_ov.html#container_cli_login

If it doesn't ask for a namespace, it means you have it already. Then try: ice login -a api.bluemix_staging_server -H containers-api.bluemix_staging_server/v2/containers -R registry.bluemix_staging_server

Note: change bluemix_staging_server by the correct hostname you are connecting to.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I've tried to invoke "ice namespace set dev" before performing login. This did not helped :(

Comment: Actually I got en error when setting namespace:

------------------------:~# ice namespace set docker
Command failed with container cloud service
{
    "code": "IC5101E",
    "description": "Org 6943da47-84c7-4fe3-b375-9ba220bfcb8b already has namespace defined: kafka",
    "incident_id": "deec2301d6c3941d",
    "name": "NamespaceAlreadyAssigned",
    "rc": "409",
    "type": "Infrastructure"
}

Comment: Try to connect via browser to Bluemix dashboard. Go to the Catalog and select create your own container. You should get a dialog asking for the namespace if it doesn't exist yet. Then, come back to command line.

Comment: Thanks Jose,
Did that, I see a window with title "Add a custom image to your private namespace in the IBM Containers registry."
Then sequence of actions to take:
 ---------------------
Download and install the Docker CLI, CloudFoundry CLI, and ibm-containers cf CLI plug-in.
Log in to Bluemix:
cf login
Run the IBM Containers cf CLI plug-in.
cf ic login
....
----------------------,
There is no dialog, are these commands replacing  dialog ? ( and I should perform described there steps) ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: If it doesn't ask for a namespace, it means you have it already. Then try: ice login -a api.bluemix_staging_server -H containers-api.bluemix_staging_server/v2/containers -R registry.bluemix_staging_server

Comment: Tried to invoke your command , got this: ice login -a api.bluemix_staging_server -H containers-api.bluemix_staging_server/v2/containers -R registry.bluemix_staging_server
API endpoint: api.bluemix_staging_server
FAILED
Error performing request: Get http://api.bluemix_staging_server/v2/info: dial tcp: lookup api.bluemix_staging_server: no such host
Authentication failed with container cloud service. Login endpoint: api.bluemix_staging_server Containers URL: https://containers-api.bluemix_staging_server/v2/containers

Comment: You should change bluemix_staging_server by the real host names. As they are internal, I can't publish them here.

Comment: Jose , thanks a lot for your help! I'm able to log-in now

Comment: Great. I updated the answer, mark it as correct if it worked for you then. Thanks.